# Present Perfect with Past Simple

Tags: tenses

As far as I know these examples are okay:

A: I had bought a new blouse. I forgot to show it to you.

B: I bought a new blouse. I forgot to show it to you.

But what about this?
C: I have bought a new blouse. I forgot to show it to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's not enough context to determine which form is preferable. But all three sentences are acceptable IMO

Answer (score 0):

I think that choice C sounds a little odd, because the present perfect is usually chosen to emphasize that the action was completed in the recent past. But "I forgot to show it to you" logically requires that a palpable interval of time has passed since the purchase.

To my ear, the logical sequel to C would be "I haven't shown it to you yet."

See the discussion of the present perfect tense at http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect.htm